# Edited question never reviewed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I edited the title of this question to be more specific and added a comment asking for suggestions but no one answered.  It seems it was simply closed after the holding period without the edit being considered.
[What's a pie chart alternative that continues to occupy a predictable amount of screen space?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/46528/whats-a-pie-chart-alternative-that-still-takes-up-a-predictable-amount-of-scree)

The answers are very good but I guess if this site only allows questions that have an absolute answer then they don't work.  I can't see that this question is any more vague than many others I've read on the site though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking over the timeline of events for that question the following happened:

- The question was asked
- It received several votes for closure for being 'too broad'
- It was reviewed by the community; several others suggested for it to be closed (although a few voted for it to remain open)
- it recieved the fifth close vote and was therefore put On Hold.
- You edited the title and left a comment.

In many cases when an On Hold question is subsequently edited it flags it for re-review to see if it's suitable for reopening. However that requires the actual body copy of the question be edited edited, whereas your edit was just the title and hasn't actually changed the content of the quetsion itself.

This is why your edit wasn't considered; it was just not noticed, not intentionally ignored.

However, having said that I still don't think the question is ideal for reopening. I think the issue is with the line "*What are some good alternatives..."*. That's because you're not actually asking for an actual solution to your problem, and therefore it's not a question that can be answered. (After all it's a Question and *Answer* site, not a question and suggestion, or a question and polling site).

If you restructure the question around a 'This is my problem, how can I solve it' then that's more suited. Questions don't need to have an *absolute* answer to be suited to the site, but they do need to be the sort of question where someone can answer "you can solve your issue by doing {this}", which you've not quite got there at the moment.

Comment: OK, thanks for the feedback.  I'll work to reword the question.  It's funny that the question as worded, even when closed, resulted in two very appropriate answers.

Comment: Just to note - the answers were left *before* the question was closed (otherwise people wouldn't have been able to leave any answers)

Comment: Of course.  Either way, my point remains the same.

Comment: OK, I reworded the title and the question body.  If it doesn't get re-opened at this point I don't have the energy to try further.  :-)  Thanks for your help.